# OSGi implementation for C?

Tags: c, osgi, implementation

Is there any OSGi implementation available for C? My search has only resulted in Apache Celix, but there is no release available for Celix yet.

Answer (score 1):

This article [OSGi and C++](http://blog.cppmicroservices.org/2012/03/29/osgi-and-c++/) talks about some projects in OSGi for C and C++.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already studied that link. But, for C it only talks about Celix which is still in incubation phase.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Celix](http://incubator.apache.org/celix/index.html) is the only publicly known C implementation of the OSGi specs.

They are [planning a 0.0.1 release](http://incubator.markmail.org/message/yx36ggk4cizearry?q=%20list%3aorg.apache.incubator.celix-dev) and there are also early efforts going on for [standardising a C/C++ OSGi API](http://blog.cppmicroservices.org/2012/05/26/native-osgi-meeting-hengelo/). Celix can certainly use early adopters to help it mature and gain more acceptance.